# I try to create a Spin Button through VBA in Excel, but it gives me an "automation error, catastrophic failure"?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Test()
    Dim spinButton As Object
    Set spinButton = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.SpinButton.1", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=276, Top:=58.5, Width:=12.75, Height:=25.5)
    spinButton.Object.Min = 1
    spinButton.Object.Max = 100
    spinButton.LinkedCell = "B2"
End Sub
```

My goal with the VBA code above is to create a simple Spin Button, which changes the value of cell "B2" by 1.

When I run the code as a macro, it gives me this error warning:

[image: error]

which [they write about on the MS website here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/automation-error-error-440).

The thing is, my code works. As in, it creates a spin button at the right location, adds the correct properties and changes the value of the B2 cell when I click the spin button.

I'm using a completely new file with nothing in it. No other macros/modules and a completely empty spreadsheet. I use my VBA code in the "ThisWorkbook" if it makes any differences:

[image: failure]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> spinButton.Object.Min = 1 
> spinButton.Object.Max = 100
> spinButton.LinkedCell = "B2"
> ```

You are getting that error because you are setting the minimum value as `1` beforehand and then linking to a cell with no value. If you do the reverse, then it will work

```
spinButton.LinkedCell = "B2"

spinButton.Object.Min = 1
spinButton.Object.Max = 100
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me with two slight changes:

1. Insert this code in a regular module, not the `ThisWorkbook` module.
2. Add a line that sets `B2`'s value to 1 before linking the spin button to it (assuming that's what you want the starting value to be, but you could just as easily set it to `100` or anything in between).

---

```
Sub Test()
    Dim spinButton As Object
    Set spinButton = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.SpinButton.1", _
        Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=276, Top:=58.5, Width:=12.75, Height:=25.5)

    spinButton.Object.Min = 1
    spinButton.Object.Max = 100

    ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value = 1
    spinButton.LinkedCell = "B2"
End Sub
```